# Shedding Light on Questions without Bounty

Tags: discussion

What is the best way to bring attention to older questions that are unanswered without starting a bounty?

Comment: Make a useful edit, which will bump the question to the top of the active tab. Share a link to the question on social media. If you can find a chatroom that does not frown upon it and is applicable to the question, potentially mentioning it in chat. If you don't want to start a bounty, social media is likely your best bet to get eyes on it, but results may vary as to getting an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't really any other **on site** way that wouldn't be considered to be abusing the system.

Adding a bounty puts the question on the "featured" tab where it can be more easily found.

The only other way to bring the question to the top of the home page is to modify it in some way:

1. Edit it.
2. Answer it.
3. Edit an answer.
4. Roll back an edit.

All of these are legitimate things to do, but if done **just** for the purpose of bumping the question then they're not on.

What you *can* do is share the link to the question on other sites and social media applications. If you use the "share" link which includes your user id you may even get a badge for it.

Comment: Good to know. I'll try it out.

Comment: If a question has no answer, it cannot be the target of a duplicate. Posting a newer encounter of the same problem can also be an option that would not be considered abusing the system.

Comment: @Travis - knowingly posting a duplicate question is not on even if the original question doesn't have an answer.

Comment: @ChrisF - I don't see any justification for that. If the new version is a better version, simply close the old one as a duplicate if an answer is posted. Then the new one is on, and the old one is off. Why would content be prevented simply to justify a line drawn in the sand?

Comment: @TravisJ - If the original has no answer, then editing is probably the solution as it will (hopefully) result in a better question.